# In the multiple select dropdowns a selected dropdown value (option) need to hide in remaining dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a web form with **3 select boxes** with multiple questions. If I select 1st Question from **1st select drop-down** that question will not appear in the **2nd select drop-down**. It will repeat same as 3rd select drop-down.

**Note:** The main purpose is if user select any questions from select drop-down that question will not appear in another select drop-down.

**Demo Code:**

```css
.margin-top-10 { margin-top: 1.0em; }
.margin-top-20 { margin-top: 2.0em; }
.margin-top-30 { margin-top: 3.0em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="">Question 1</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                                    <option selected="">Choose your question</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 1</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 2</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 3</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 4</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12 margin-top-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="">Question 2</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                                    <option selected="">Choose your question</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 1</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 2</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 3</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 4</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12 margin-top-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="">Question 3</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                                    <option selected="">Choose your question</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 1</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 2</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 3</option>
                                                    <option>Select question 4</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12 margin-top-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                
                                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                            <a href="Create-Username-Password.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Back</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6"><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="Registration-Complete.html" name="btnGlassContactInfo">Register <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post you JS code and a more specific error/issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you might want to do if change the select elements in your code so that each of them has a unique ID. They are all sel1 at the moment :)

Then you need to bind the *onchange* event to the select options that will remove the option being selected. Here is an example:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var elem = this;
  var option = this.value;
  $('.form-control option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() === option && $(elem).attr('id') !== $(this).parent().attr('id')) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
})
```

You would probably want to disable the user from using the same selection element, or store the removed options and add them back should the user change his / her mind.

I have disabled them in my example, which you can view here.
https://jsfiddle.net/martiensk/jwfeqrx0/

Comment: Thanks for code, I have checked your code If I select any question after I want to change the question. It does not re selected

Comment: I changed removed options it works perfect. Because the first option disable.